# Simple way in R to create a column incrementing within a group by two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, increment, calculated-columns

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
type = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))

> df
  id type
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  1  b
4  1  b
5  1  b
6  2  a
7  2  a
8  2  a
9  2  b
10 2  b
```

I would like to create a column that increments 1, 2, 3, ... within each 'id' and 'type' group like so:

```
  id type inst
1  1  a    1
2  1  a    2
3  1  b    1
4  1  b    2
5  1  b    3
6  2  a    1
7  2  a    2
8  2  a    3
9  2  b    1
10 2  b    2
```

What is a simple way to do this?